# Ubuntu 12.10 stuck in incomplete upgrade state

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10, dependencies

I started upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10 x64. All of a sudden, the upgrade process stops due to `extra.ubuntu.com` being unreachable. Any attempts to resume the process didn't give any results. The attempts were as follows:

```
 1. sudo apt-get -f install
 2. sudo dpkg --configure -a
 3. sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
    sudo apt-get clean
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

In all cases, the process `dpkg --config libc6:amd64` stopped working due to too many errors, because 13 packages have wrong versions (below than required) and such files cannot be configured and thus upgraded. Each attempt to upgrade them caused the stop of dpkg configuration process due to broken dependencies. Synaptic doesn't help as well as it runs the same upgrade process.

**Is there any way to remove such broken dependencies?**

At the moment the system shows that this is Ubuntu 12.10. If I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get as result many pages with error messages, but the last part is as follows:

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping Errors were encountered while processing:

 - texlive-base
 - texlive-doc-base
 - rhythmbox-plugins
 - rhythmbox
 - texlive-binaries
 - texlive-extra-utils
 - rhythmbox-mozilla
 - rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
 - libc6:amd64
 - libc6:i386
 - libglib2.0-cil
 - rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 - monodevelop-versioncontrol
 - libdee-1.0-4
 - libmono-posix4.0-cil
 - libgee2:amd64
 - libcolord1:amd64
 - libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64
 - libglib2.0-cil-dev
 - rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 - libfontenc1:amd64
 - cpio
 - libmono-system2.0-cil
 - pulseaudio
 - xserver-xorg-video-ati
 - xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
 - dconf-service
 - libmono-system-data-linq2.0-cil
 - libmono-sqlite2.0-cil
 - libapr1
 - policykit-1
 - libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil
 - gconf-defaults-service
 - xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
 - libexempi3:amd64
 - libgtkspell0
 - libgtk2.0-cil-dev
 - libbonoboui2-0:amd64
 - libclutter-1.0-0:amd64
 - libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil
 - libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64
 - libpth20
 - mono-runtime
 - libsocket6-perl
 - libart-2.0-2:amd64
 - libpam-cap:amd64
 - libpoppler28:amd64
 - libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
 - gvfs-bin
 - libmono-system-data2.0-cil
 - libmono-system-web4.0-cil

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

I realized that I didn't put the essential part of the log which states the fact that all such modules cannot be configured as because broken dependencies - packages, aforementioned packages depend on have old versions, from Ubuntu 12.04.

I added the list in the log as I don't know how better place each package name on a string.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the relevant information instead of commenting it? You can use the formatting options to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I put everything in the question body.

Comment: It looks there are not replies, so I decided to reinstall from scratch the system and it works. As I use a separate partition for /home, the full reinstallation is not as bad as others cases. Thank you, Vlad.